# how to distribute percentages across 4 input fields using angular ng change

Tags: angularjs, scope

```
 $scope.calculatePercentage  =  function(country)
 {
   if(country == "us")
   {
      $scope['europe'] = $scope.total - $scope[country] ;   
      $scope['asia'] = 0;
      $scope['rest'] = 0;
   }
   else if(country == "europe")
   {
      $scope['europe'] = $scope.total - $scope[country] ;   
      $scope['asia'] = 0;
      $scope['rest'] = 0; 
   }


 }
```

Please see the above code and attached plucker link
If user updates any of the fields,the next field should get updated with the difference and all the values should add up to 100.
if user enters second field with 50 , then the values should be 0,50,50,0
if user enter third field with 30, then the values should be 0,50,30,20 and so on

[PLNKR Preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/AsdPUoGCwMlckP8DLq8g?p=preview)

Comment: In order to better understand: case1 = 0,50,0,0 -> 0,50,50,0; case2 = 0,50,30,0 -> 0,50,30,20; what if I enter 50 in the third position?

Comment: if u enter 50 in third position , then 0,0,50,50. every time user updates any of the values, the others should be updated to add up to 100 everytime.

Comment: Sorry but it is still unclear to me the behavior of how the fields should update. In your example, "if user enter third field with 30, then the values should be 0,50,30,20" why is this not 50,0,30,20 if I keep updating the fields in turn?